# Use gMSA account in TFS pipeline

Tags: tfs, gmsa

Can we use gMSA account in TFS Release pipeline? I am trying to use gMSA account for 'Windows Machine File Copy' task but since I don't have the password for gMSA account, I specify an empty string.

But when I run, I get the following error

### [error]Failed to Create PSDrive with Destination: '\Servername\D$\Path', ErrorMessage: 'Access is denied'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. gMSA account, currently not supported in TFS.

However, there has been a related user voice:

> *Support for Active Directory Group Managed Service Accounts*
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365494/support-for-active-directory-group-managed-service.html

You could vote up and track the process, our PM will kindly review any feature request.

If there is not a specific reason you need  to run a gMSA account, you could use local system admin account and domain account instead.

**Admin Login:**

The username of either a domain or a local administrative account on the target host(s).

- Formats such as domain\username, username, and machine-name\username
  are supported.
- UPN formats such as username@domain.com and built-in system accounts
  such as NT Authority\System are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The reason why we were using gMSA account was not have to manage passwords. Anyhow, it seems we will need to use a normal domain account for now.

Comment: There is not much traction on that user voice. In fact it seems to be pretty much ignored.